# python plot two time points with slope

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot several diagrams as a FacetGrid, each one including two times points. In addition I want to calculate and display the slope of the line:

```
ID     TimePoint1    TimePoint2
================================
A      500           20000
B      200           1000
C      3000          50000
```

Something like this:
[image]

I tried this code example but nothing shows up in the plots:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_table("test.csv", sep=",")
g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col="ID", col_wrap=4, height=2, ylim=(0, 10))
g.map(sns.pointplot, "TimePoint1", "TimePoint2", color=".3", ci=None)
```

How can I achieve this with seaborn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you used TimePoint1 as x and TimePoint2 as y. To achieve what you want you need to reshape your data first. Assuming `data` the input data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data_long = (data.rename(columns=lambda x: int(x[-1]) if x.startswith('TimePoint') else x)
                 .melt(id_vars=['ID'], var_name='TimePoint')
             )
g = sns.FacetGrid(data_long, col="ID", col_wrap=4, height=2,) # ylim=(0, 10))
g.map(sns.pointplot, "TimePoint", "value", color=".3", ci=None)
```

output:

[image: seaborn pointplot]

*NB. I removed your ylim that was invalid*

data_long:

```
  ID TimePoint  value
0  A         1    500
1  B         1    200
2  C         1   3000
3  A         2  20000
4  B         2   1000
5  C         2  50000
```

You can also conveniently use [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) that is a wrapper around FacetGrid:

```
sns.catplot(data=df_long, x='TimePoint', y='value', col='ID',
            col_wrap=4, height=2, color=".3", ci=None, kind='point'
           )
```

Comment: side note: OP can simplify `FacetGrid`+`map` using the [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) wrapper: `sns.catplot(x="TimePoint", y="value", col="ID", col_wrap=4, height=2, color=".3", ci=None, kind="point", data=data_long)`

Comment: @tdy Yes, true, I just used OP original code, but it's a very good point. I updated the answer.

Comment: @mozway I see, didn't realize that I have to reformat the data. Thanks!